# Building Arm libraries

Tags: build, arm

I am new to ARM and building stuff. So question may be very simple. I have project which uses some libraries. This libraries built in Arm format. I want to change something in this libraries but their source code is x86 format. So I think that I have to build arm libraries from this format but I have no idea how to achieve this. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "their source code is x86 format"?

As you want to build libraries for ARM you can use the same source code to build libraries either by setting up a cross compilation toolchain or building the source code onto the ARM system itself.

Although if there is any dependency of platform libraries, you need to make sure that those libraries are available in your cross compilation toolchain or onto the ARM system.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lack of information in my post. Firstly sorry for that. Source code of the libraries are in different places from the my arm project. In arm project there isn't any source code. I didn't design this project. I want to change only few things. But to change these things I need to update source code of libraries. After some search I found source code totally different places. It has no effect on building process of arm projects. So I think that I can use this source code to create updated libraries. But MakeFiles of this source code designed for x86 architecture. I don't how build arm type libraries from this source code.